# MacOS: No write permissions after copy files from Windows

Tags: networking, mac, permissions

I have Mac mini (High Sierra 10.13.3) as a server. Server has external HDD formated as Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I'm using a PC (Windows 10, NTFS) for downloading files. When I copy files (LAN, SMB protocol) from my PC to my Mac mini, the Mac mini administrator (me) doesn't have permissions for read/write and I can't open new files.

[image: No permissions screenshot]

So I have to add my user and set the right permissions.

[image: Correct permissions screenshot]

It is very annoying to do that every time when I copy something new. Do you have some easy solution, how to fix this once for all?

Comment: This may well be a configuration issue with the samba server.

Comment: @Attie. Maybe, I don't understand it. Could you help me where/what to config?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Macs unfortunately... do you see a file `/private/etc/smb.conf`?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites, pick one & stick to it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316205/no-write-permissions-after-copy-files-from-windows

Comment: @Attie I found only "smb.conf.old" from 22/5/2009. I looked into it but I didn't find anything related to permissions.